# Override GridLayout's padding

Tags: android

I have a `GridLayout` with `android:padding="16dp"` and I have some divider in it

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_columnSpan="2"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
```

I'd like the divider to be as wide as the `GridLayout` is. How can I override the padding? Negative padding/margin didn't work.

(I have more views than dividers so setting padding in that views would lead to much more redundancy)